# Is it possible to create a Python application that subscribes to parts of a firebase project

Tags: python, firebase

I have a scenario where there is a firebase project, and I would like to monitor certain events that they make public.

An event happens, and I would like to subscribe to that, and send out a notification.  From what I can see with python there is the firebase_admin library, and I can call initialize. The issue is that I don't have a login. In talking with the developer of the project their belief is that since they are publishing that data publicly, I should not need to authenticate.

But when I read this documentation, it want me to have a json credential file, or authenticate with gcloud

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python_1

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Application Default credentials are automatically created.
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
db = firestore.client()
```

Is there any way to get around this and subscribe without providing credentials?

I just want to get to where I can make these types of calls assuming the results are public and not behind authentication.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) assume that you're a trusted collaborator on the project, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

The non-Firebase [Google Cloud Python libraries for Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest) also seem to assume some form of [administrative access](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html), which you don't have.

I don't see any existing other Python SDK from Google to access Firestore, so you may have to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest).